# How can I play sounds that are stored in assets or raw resource folder if the specific file to play depends on an SQLite Query?

Tags: android, sqlite, soundpool

I am finding a way how to play sounds in my resource folder (res or assets, in whichever appropriate way to store) but the file that will be loaded to the soundpool or mediaplayer depends on an SQLite query.

I am currently making a translator app that displays word or sentence translations via search engine (just noting that this app is just an search engine, not really a translator like Google Translate). and I need a 'pronounce' button that will play how to pronounce the searched word to its dialect, and this file (it was pre-recorded) will be stored in a resource folder. It's like, when the user searched the word "apple", and the button was clicked, it will play the "apple.mp3" in the resource folder.

I'm just new to Android programming and I search from the web and found answers about soundpools and mediaplayer but I think I hadn't seen any like this before.

Comment: see this might help http://www.lynda.com/Android-tutorials/Setting-up-audio-playback/79825/87063-4.html

Comment: i do have almost 300+ in my SQLite dbase, and each entry has an equivalent "xxx.mp3" in the res folder. that tutorial only tackles how to control sound thru mediaplayer, and its just a single file. in my case, i do have 5 buttons dedicated to each dialect in which the searched word or sentence is translated.

Comment: Keep the references to the resources in your database and when you query your data then you can easily access your sound files

Comment: I agree with @Mieszko

Comment: just get file name from your process and then play specific file

Comment: can you translate your answer in code @Mieszko? :))

Answer (score 1):

According to my comment:

1. Create one more column in your database table
2. Put your references into this column (i.e. R.raw.my_sound.mp3) (!remember reference is always int!)
3. When you query get value from this column and use it like this ( I didn't test it. It's more like pseudo code ;) ):

   ```
   Cursor cursor = database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, 
   new String[] { KEY_REFERENCES }, WORD + " = " + insertedWord, null, null, null, null); 
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
      int reference = cursor.getInt(referenceColumnIndex);
      MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(YourActivityClass.this, reference);
      if(mp != null) {
         mp.start();
      }
   }
   ```

I think it should work.

Comment: haha thanks there @mieszko , ill try it immediately when i got home.